# Jquery parents not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one question about jquery parents.

I created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/JoEXqX)** from *codepen.io*

In this demo you can see there is a tree link *Show div*, *Show div2* and *Show div3*. If you click *Show div* then jquery code will open `.popup` and `.openingdiv` but other link not working in the same code. Anyone can help me here?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.click').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   $('.popup').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
   $('.popup').css('display', 'block');
   $(this).parent().next('.openingdiv').toggleClass('height');
     $(this).toggleClass('zindex');

  $('.closediv a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 500, 'linear');
   $('.popup').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).closest('.openingdiv').removeClass('height');
  });
})
  $('.click2').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   $('.popup').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
   $('.popup').css('display', 'block');
   $(this).parent().next('.openingdiv2').toggleClass('height');
     $(this).toggleClass('zindex');

  $('.closediv2 a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 500, 'linear');
   $('.popup').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).closest('.openingdiv2').removeClass('height');
  });
})

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="click"><a href="#">Show Div</a></div>
  <div class="click2"><a href="#">Show Div2</a></div>
  <div class="click3"><a href="#">Show Div3</a></div>
</div>
<div class="openingdiv">
  <div class="closediv"><a href="#">close</a></div>
</div>
<div class="openingdiv2">
  <div class="closediv2"><a href="#">close2</a></div>
</div>
<div class="openingdiv3">
  <div class="closediv3"><a href="#">close3</a></div>
</div>

<div class="popup"></div>
```

Comment: Paste your code here such that it is preserved for future visitors.

Comment: You are using `.next()` on each `.click`, so, all clicks are going to `.opendiv`, and not to their respective elements.

Comment: @klauskpm What should i do?

Comment: You can use `.siblings()`, instead of `.next()`, with the selector in it. http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Adding click events inside of click events is a bad idea.

Comment: @epascarello  Not working my friend

Comment: I could be off base here but I think @epascarello is saying regardless of whether it works or not, it's not a good idea to embed `.click` events inside of other `.click` events. Have you looked into event delegation? This way you could have a single handler and identify the element by the target of the event (i.e. `event.target`) to find which element triggered the event?

Comment: Look into `$(document).on('click',selector,function() {...})` for binding event listeners

Comment: @War10ck Yes i still try event but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this pen here. It uses .on() to bind the events

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPdgmK (UPDATED)

```
<html>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="click button" data-opener="1"><a href="#">Show Div</a></div>
    <div class="click2 button" data-opener="2"><a href="#">Show Div2</a></div>
    <div class="click3 button" data-opener="3"><a href="#">Show Div3</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="openingdiv1 opener">
    <div class="closediv closer"><a href="#">close</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="openingdiv2 opener">
    <div class="closediv closer"><a href="#">close2</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="openingdiv3 opener">
    <div class="closediv closer"><a href="#">close3</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="popup"></div>

</html>

<style>


.container{
  width:540px;
  height:auto;
  margin:0px auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.click{
  float:left;
  width:64px;
  height:64px;
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:arial,sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:64px;
}
.click2{
  float:left;
  width:69px;
  height:64px;
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:arial,sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:64px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
.click3{
  float:left;
  width:69px;
  height:64px;
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:arial,sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:64px;

}
.popup {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#000;
  opacity: .0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  z-index:300;
  display:none;
}
.opener {
  float:left;
  width:540px;
  height:0;
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
  z-index:999;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
  -o-transition: height 1s ease;
  transition: height 1s ease;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.opener.height {
  height: 200px;
}

.zindex {
   z-index:9999;
   position:relative;   
}
.closer {
  padding:15px;
  float:right;
  margin:0px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
}
.closer a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:13px;
  font-family:arial,sans-serif;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document)
  .on('click','.button',function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var opener = $(this).data('opener');
    $('.popup').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
    $('.popup').css('display', 'block');
    $('.openingdiv'+opener).addClass('height');
    //$(this).toggleClass('zindex');
  })

  .on('click','.closediv a',function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.popup').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 500, 'linear');
    $('.popup').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).closest('.opener:visible').removeClass('height');
  })

; // $(document)
</script>
```

Comment: in theory, you could just use `.on('click','.click, .click2, .click3',function(event){...})` but I assume you will want something different in each event. you can also determine which is clicked with data attributes

Comment: Your code working only `.openingdiv` but my question is when you click `.click2` then `.openingdiv2` will open also same like when you click `.click3` then open `.openingidv3`

Comment: Still `.opening` div opens. Other `.click2` and `.click3` not opening `.openingdiv2` and `.openingdiv3`

Comment: The problem Wes with your styles. The height style was only applied to the first openingdiv in the stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have used

`$('.popup').css('display', 'block');`

Could you use 'none' in order to active other links or write it in another way totally?